# SQL show rows with unique values only

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm losing my mind with a silly novice problem! I'm trying to write a command in SQLite to show only rows with unique values from a selected column.

An example:

```
Product  | Price
Cheese   | 5
Yogurt   | 2
Milk     | 2
Soy Milk | 3
```

I want the result to be

```
Cheese
Soy Milk
```

I imagine the answer is super simple. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following using `IN`

```
select
    product
from yourTable
where price not in
(
   select
     price 
   from yourTable
   group by
     price
   having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.price = t.price and t2.product <> t.product);
```

Or, aggregation:

```
select max(product)
from t
group by price
having count(*) = 1;
```